# How to convert ActiveRecord table name to model class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is there any possibility to properly convert ActiveRecord table name to model class name? I have found one hack

```
def model_for_table(table_name)
  table_name.classify.constantize
end
```

but since we use set_table_name for many of our models this wont work. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did it!

This returns a hash in the form of "table_name" => "model_class_name".

```
Hash[ObjectSpace.enum_for(:each_object, class << ActiveRecord::Base; 
    self; end).to_a.reject{|c| c == ActiveRecord::Base}.collect{
    |c| [c.table_name, c.name]}]
```

EDIT: **Better version** (works with Rails 3 only):

```
Hash[ActiveRecord::Base.send(:descendants).collect{|c| [c.table_name, c.name]}]
```

Please note not all your model classes are always loaded. To **load them all** before creating such a hash do this:

```
Dir.foreach("#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/models") { |f| require f if f =~ /.*\.rb/ }
```

Nice.

Comment: Probably way late, but (at least with newer Ruby/Rails versions) you can do it like this: `Dir[Rails.root.join("app", "models", "**", "*.rb")].each(&method(:require)); ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.index_by(&:table_name)`

Comment: Not all models live in `app/models`. Some live (or are created) in gems.

Comment: For Rails 6, some tables map to class names prefixed by `HABTM_`, should also remove them before `collect` the results by `ObjectSpace.each_object(class << ActiveRecord::Base; self; end).to_a.reject { |c| c == ActiveRecord::Base || c.name.include?('HABTM_') }.collect { |c| [c.table_name, c.name] }.to_h`.

Answer (score 2):

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select{ |klass| 
  klass < ActiveRecord::Base 
}.index_by(&:table_name)
```

It is not the fastest thing in the world though

Comment: Thanks. I have found the solution but you inspired me how to do it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Can do like this in rails 3:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.collect{|c| [c.table_name, c.name]}
```